# Тоже по этимологии

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "упырь"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Упырь** - "вампир, труп злого колдуна или ведьмы, который бродит ночью в образе волка или совы и убивает людей и животных. Чтобы избавиться от него, нужно разрыть его могилу и пробить труп колом" (Даль), укр. упирь, род. п. -я, блр. упiр, др.-русск. *Упирь* -- имя в Кн. пророков под 1047 г., болг. въпиръ, чеш., слвц. upir, польск. upior (судя по начальному u-, заимств. из вост.-слав.).

Реконструкция праслав. формы сопряжена с трудностями: *ọруrь или* ọpirь сближают -руrь с *нетопырь*. По другой версии - *ọpirь и сближается с* парить, перо*. Согласно Соболевскому, нем. Vampir "вампир" происходит из полаб. или др.-польск. Мошинский сравнивает это слово с сербохорв. пирати "дуть". Сомнительно в фонетическом отношении популярное толкование из тат. ubyr "мифологическое существо", которое связывают с uрmаk "глотать". Неприемлема также этимология от авест. vymbura- "враждебный воде", др.-инд. ambu ср. р. "вода". (Фасмер)